# Limiting the number of request from any given IP address

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am working on a Google App Engine project (python/webapp2) where I am a little concerned with people abusing/spamming the service I am creating with a large number of requests. In an attempt to combat this potential, my idea is to limit the number of requests allowed per IP address in any given hour for certain parts of the applicaiton. My current plan is as follows:

On each request I will:

1. grab the ip address from the header
2. store this ip address in the dataStore with a time stamp
3. delete any ip address entities in that are over an hour old
4. count the number of dataStore entities with that IP address
5. disallow access if there are more than given limit

My question is this:
Is this the best way to go about this?  I am only a beginner here and I imagine that there is quite a bit of overhead of doing it this way and that possibly this is a common task that might have a better solution.  Is there any better way to do this that is less resource intensive?

Comment: One thing to worry about is NAT.  If you have a large number of users behind a NAT system (e.g. a corporation or even some ISPs), the incoming address you see will be the same for all users (or spread out over a small set).

Comment: +1 to DrC. But it's worth noting that many services do this anyway—everything from small services like AmpliFIND up to giants like Twitter. The usual way around this is to give devs and/or end-users an option to use some kind of per-user/-system/-program/-whatever authentication (e.g., OAuth tokens).

Comment: For static IP addresses you can use the **Denial of Service** configuration file dos.xml in your app. Just blacklist IP addresses that abuse your service and re-deploy your app as described on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/dos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the past, I've done this with memcache, which is much faster, especially since you only really care about approximate limits (approximate because memcache can be flushed by the system, might not be shared by all instances, etc.). You can even use it to expire keys for you. Something like this (which assumes `self` is a webapp2 request handler, and you've imported GAE's memcache library):

```
memcache_key = 'request-count-' + self.request.remote_addr

count = memcache.get(memcache_key)

if count is not None and count > MAX_REQUESTS:
    logging.warning("Remote user has %d requests; rejecting." % (count))
    self.error(429)
    return

count = memcache.incr(memcache_key)
if count is None:
    # key didn't exist yet
    memcache.add(memcache_key, 1, time=WINDOW_IN_SECONDS)
```

This will create a key which rejects users after about MAX_REQUESTS in WINDOW_IN_SECONDS time, re-zeroing the count each WINDOW_IN_SECONDS. (i.e. it's not a sliding window; it resets to zero each time period.)

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Really simple and you even gave me a huge start with the code.  Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Note that you should check `count is not None and count > MAX_REQUESTS` in your first if statement, in case the key hasn't been set in Memcache yet.

Answer (score 2):

First, two caveats with your design:

- It's often very easy for someone to get a new IP address—switch your iPhone from LTE to 3G and back, unplug and replug your DSL model, pick a new open proxy, etc. So, if you're expecting this to prevent intentional abuse rather than just people not realizing they're doing too much, it's not much help.
- IP addresses are often shared, either by [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), or sequentially. Maybe 200 requests per hour per IP seems reasonable if that means one person—but what if it means all 7500 employees at BigCorp's regional office?

Anyway, your solution will work, and, depending on your traffic patterns it may be reasonable, but there are a few alternatives.

For example, instead of checking on every connection, you may want to keep a shared blacklist. When a connection comes in, immediately accept or reject based on that blacklist, and kick off an "update the database" job. You can do further tricks to coalesce the updates, not update more often than once every N seconds, etc. Of course this means you now have shared data that's readable by all connections and writable by some background job, which means you've opened the door to race conditions and deadlocks and all the fun things that Guido tried hard to make sure you rarely have to face with GAE.

You can use memcache instead of dataStore. However, you need to carefully rework your keys so they make sense for a simple key-value store and so expiry does what you want. For example, you might keep a value keyed off the IP plus a timestamp or random number or whatever for each connection, plus a list-of-connections value keyed off the IP that lets you find the other values. Any value that's dropped out of the cache no longer counts, and if the list-of-connections value drops, the user must be down to 0. But this adds a lot of complexity.

If you have a small number of users each making a whole lot of requests, you could use a timer to decrement or reset or re-count for each IP. However, if you expect more than a few hundred distinct IPs per hour, you need to manually coalesce all these timers, and probably coalesce the jobs as well (e.g., "at 17:55:39, decrement this list of 17 IPs"), and the timer will probably be firing so often that it's probably not worth it.

Personally, I'd do the simplest implementation first, then stress-test and performance-test it, and if it's good enough, stop worrying.

And if it's *not* good enough, I might look into whether I could simplify the design before looking at optimizing the implementation. For example, if it's N connections per IP per *calendar-hour*, that makes everything a whole lot easier—just store a counter per IP (in dataStore or memcache), and wipe all the counters at every XX:00. Is that acceptable?

Comment: These are all excellent suggestions I will have to look into.  Thanks for the help